# Launch chromium from puppeteer without puppeteer functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium

How can I **launch chromium installed in node_modules directly** puppeteer without puppeteer functionality (only launch browser)? I assume that there is a switch when calling `launch`, but I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.
A browser path and some universal launch code would also help, but unfortunately I can't even create it.

So, how to launch puppeteer browser directly (bypass puppeteer)?

Comment: Puppeteer is open source. The relevant files are [BrowserFetcher.ts](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/src/BrowserFetcher.ts) and [BrowserRunner.ts](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/src/launcher/BrowserRunner.ts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`puppeteer.executablePath()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#puppeteerexecutablepath) gives you the path to the executable file.

Quote from the documentation:

> returns: <[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)> A path where Puppeteer expects to find the bundled browser. The browser binary might not be there if the download was skipped with [`PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#environment-variables).

You can then use Node.js itself to [create a process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). See example:

```js
import { executablePath } from 'puppeteer';
import { execFile } from 'child_process';

chromiumParams = ['--no-first-run', '--no-default-browser-check'];
chromiumPath = executablePath();
execFile(chromiumPath, chromiumParams, (error, stdout) => {
  if (error) { throw error; }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```